Are discontinuities in the Ubuntu Hardware Certification lists indicative?
It seems that some laptops are listed as certified for Ubuntu 20.04 but not for 22.04. Is there really no continual certification testing of new releases for models that have been certified for earlier ones?
For example, Dell Vostro 3420 is currently listed as only certified for 20.04. How would you personally calibrate the risk of a failed system, failing devices, or lengthy tinkering and loss of work days for upgrading it to 22.04 and later versions?
In the past, I had always lost days of work fixing up Ubuntu to fully work on laptops, and sometimes had to give up on using some devices and built-in hardware device features altogether, on laptops where I installed Ubuntu. This was before using the certification lists.

"Continual certification" would be up to the OEMs who lend their hardware for testing. Lent hardware sometimes must be returned. OEMs change their interest in Linux testing. It's a rich tapestry.

"The risk of a failed system" due to hardware incompatibility seems low, as you can can readily test hardware using a LiveUSB. A regression may be more likely; when you discover one please file a proper bug report so it can be fixed.

Thanks for the insider view @user535733, and the comments!

Since the Linux Kernel (and therefore also Ubuntu) are mostly backwards hardware compatible (drivers for new hardware are added, but generally not removed for older hardware), common logic would indicate that hardware certified for Ubuntu 20.04 would also be 100% compatible with newer versions of Ubuntu (like 22.04).
Hardware certified only for Ubuntu 22.04 will still likely work with Ubuntu 20.04 if you use the HWE (Hardware Enablement) line of kernels, but this is probably not tested by the manufacturer.
Keep in mind that many laptops not on the certified list will still run Ubuntu without any issues.

Thanks for chiming in. Either my understanding of the driver development lifecycle is shaky, or I don't necessarily resonate how logic indicates 100% forward compatibility, in case drivers are updated (say for bug fixes etc.) without being tested on some of the hardwares that they support. Say if a single driver supports multiple devices and not tested against some of them after being updated between releases of Ubuntu. Maybe some education about the lifecycle of driver integration into Ubuntu may shed some additional helpful light.

That's why I said "mostly" backwards compatible. There may of course be edge cases, but generally the kernel will not remove drivers for hardware that was once supported.
